# How can i test data source connections configured in Tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, jdbc

I'm moving from Websphere server to Tomcat and looking for any open source tools which might aid the manageability of my application. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the application level, within the dbcp configuration, you can specify directives like validationQuery and testOnBorrow which perform the same function as WebSphere. You can google "tomcat dbcp" to get more details on the various options.